# Unit test for Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper

Tags: c#, nunit, rhino-mocks

Our project is using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper to read and write data from a database.

Is it possible to write unit test for the `SqlHelper` class using mock? If yes, then how?

Comment: Is this your own code? If not : why are you testing other people's code? That's **their** responsibility - not yours ....

Comment: We have used sqlhelper to return dataser and inserting or updating data to database. We are writing unit tests for our codeonly. but I am not able to mock using rhino mock because its a sealed class